# Added more fields to a form but the changes aren't showing up

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Title pretty much sums it up. I added some new fields to a form that a group member created, but when I runserver I can't see the changes. I render it in the view, changed the form in forms.py, added the view to urls.py, tried linking it to a model (idk why this would work, but a TA suggested it). In the template I use form.as_p to display it. Right now only the volunteer_hours char input field is displaying. Does anyone know what I might have done wrong?

forms.py:

```
class VolunteerForm(forms.Form):
volunteer_title = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter event name'})
day = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Day (DD)'})
month = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Month (MM)'})
year = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Year (YYYY)'})
volunteer_hours = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the number of hours'})
```

views.py:

```
class VolunteerView(CreateView):
form_class = VolunteerForm template_name = 'volunteer.html'
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): form = VolunteerForm() render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = VolunteerForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid(): pass
args = {'form': form} return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.donate, name='donate'),
path('payment', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment'), path('payment/thanks', ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'), path('volunteer', VolunteerView.as_view(), name='volunteer') ]
```

volunteer.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<!-- Bootstrap and starter template -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="
sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!---->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Volunteer Forms</h1>
<br><br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Volunteer</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
<!-- Footer -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #191970;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="footer">
<p>©2020 By 3 Cavaliers (2-17)</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FormView` instead of `CreateView`.
use this code:

```
class VolunteerView(generic.FormView):
form_class = VolunteerForm
template_name = 'volunteer.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(VolunteerView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pass
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```